# Stack space overflow error message during `pandoc` conversion (large data?)

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, pandoc, rcharts

I am trying to replicate [this excellent page.](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_dygraphs/retail.html)

When I knit [markdown file `retail.Rmd` from GitHub](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_dygraphs), using `RStudio (v0.98.729)`, I get the error message:

> output file: retail.knit.md
>
> G:/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc retail.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output retail.html --filter G:/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc-citeproc --section-divs --smart --self-contained --template G:\R\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html --variable jquery:G:\R\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\jquery-1.10.2 --variable bootstrap:G:\R\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\bootstrap-3.0.3 --variable theme:G:\R\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\bootstrap-3.0.3\css\bootstrap.min.css --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=G:\R\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\highlight --mathjax --variable mathjax-url:https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
>
> Stack space overflow: current size 16777216 bytes.
>   Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed
>   Execution halted

I suspect the error is related to the size of the underlying data (8.6MB), because when I do the following and knit again, the error message disappears:

```
french_industry_xts <- french_industry_xts[1:10000,]
```

How to increase the size of the stack space, as the error message suggests?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem... Did you get the solution?

Comment: Not yet. Any idea who to contact?

Comment: Usually, people at stackoverflow answer open questions within a day. I have also open a similar question, let's see how people respond to that... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599860/how-to-increase-stack-space-overflow-for-pandoc-in-r