# How to increase stack space overflow for pandoc in R?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am getting the following error with Knit HTML:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 16777216 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
```

I am trying to solve the issue by adding the following lines on the top of markdown script:

````
 ```r
pandoc +RTS -K64m -RTS -f rst -
```
````

I was just wondering if the code is correct or where shall I place the code to make it work?

Comment: You might have to knit to an md file then either programmatically add those arguments to pandoc via [the knitr demo docs](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/) or on the command-line directly. It's not optimal, but it should work.

Comment: I *just* noticed [this](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) tidbit on RStudio's rmarkdown page. I think adding the pandoc options that way (in the YAML front matter) should work as well. (scroll down on that page to "Pandoc Arguments")

Comment: Please post what worked for you as an answer and accept it to remove this question from the knitr unanswered uestions list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for not putting in the answer;).  I have no idea what 'this tidbit' means

Comment: I have tried to do exactly as suggested in the YAML front matter by adding  `"+RTS -K64m -RTS -f rst -"` and `"+RTS -K64m -RTS"` like this: `---
title: "whatever"
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "+RTS -K64m -RTS -f rst -"
    ]
---` This results consistently in the following error message: `openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1`

Comment: additional info: `knit2html` works without issues and generates both an md and html file, so the issue really lies with pandoc

Comment: I don't know where else to ask for help than here on SO because it is a very specific problem. I would like to hear back from the original posters how they solved their issue rather than reopen a new one.

Comment: @FM Kerckhof Pandoc is a big pain. Sometimes it work while the others it does not. I remember using the instructions on [on this page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) and it worked for me.

Comment: @M.Qasim I also followed those instructions as good as possible but it just doesn't work. Would this maybe require posting a new question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Solution:** Add the following code snippet at the beginning of your Rmd file to increase the stack size:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "+RTS", "-K64m",
      "-RTS"
    ]
---
```

Comment: Thank you for this input. How did you find this out? I can't seem to find it in the pandoc documentatin. This worked for me and I am very happy to find it here :-) Thank you so much!

Comment: How I did find it out?
I looked at the [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) (section "Pandoc Arguments") and saw that the pandoc arguments must be specified as array elements (one item per argument):

Comment: that was not entirerly clear to me from the Pandoc Arguments section, I was assuming these were some kind of key/value combinations...

Comment: @FMKerckhof, what do you mean where did he find it out? His name is R Yoda

Comment: This might be its own question, but this does not seem to work for R Notebooks ("Error creating notebook: Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 7, column 3 found character that cannot start any token at line 7, column 3". My line 7 is "html_notebook". If this isn't sufficiently similar, I'll start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible workaround. After failing to resolve the error using the RStudio GUI button to 'Knit HTML', the following generated the expected HTML file.

```
library(knitr)
knit2html('./myNotes.Rmd')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This workaround also works in my case, although I would want to know how we can avoid it and use the Rstudio GUI.