# Pandoc & Rstudio Knitr memory leak

Tags: ubuntu, memory, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to knit an .Rmd file on a private ubuntu amazon ec2 instance with 15GB of memory. I  installed rstudio (RStudio 0.99.903 - Ubuntu 12.04+/Debian 8+ (64-bit)) from source without a problem and then linked the accompanied version of pandoc following [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md#newer-systems-debianubuntufedora).

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc /usr/local/bin
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc-citeproc /usr/local/bin
```

And confirmed its in PATH

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-87:~$ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.15.2
```

Invoking knitr from command line

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Observed.Rmd')" &> run.txt
```

I can successfully knit small test runs.

However when i try a larger run i get the error

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS SingleSpecies.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output SingleSpecies.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained -M2GB +RTS -K64m -RTS --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template /home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --number-sections --variable 'theme:spacelab' --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpWXb9A4/rmarkdown-str58570a61934.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight --variable navigationjs=/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rmarkdown/rmd/h/navigation-1.0 
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
Execution halted
Warning message:
system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

I have tried increase heap size, following another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599860/how-to-increase-stack-space-overflow-for-pandoc-in-r), by adding to the YAML

```
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: yes
    theme: spacelab
    toc: yes
    pandoc_args: [
    "-M2GB", "+RTS", "-K64m", "-RTS"
    ]
```

I have also tried

```
self_contained: no
```

From which i can see that the figures being knit are **only a total of 40MB**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-194:~/Whales$ du SingleSpecies_files/ -sh
40M     SingleSpecies_files/
```

On e2c, I am tracking the memory in five minute increments.

[image]

And i can see that knitr (or pandoc) starts to eat memory, **more than 10GB** in five minutes. What is causing this leak? Yes there are several dozen figures, some stemming from ggmap, but they nowhere near account for all of the memory allocation. I recognize this is not reproducible, but i've tried to be thorough. All suggestions welcome.

I suspect that since i am running knitr outside of rstudio, there is an rstudio environmental variable which stabilizes large knitr runs?

Comment: Could you share your Rmd file? My guess: Look at that...

Comment: .Rmd is here: https://github.com/bw4sz/Whales/blob/master/SingleSpecies.Rmd

Comment: I have the same problem with a little `ggmap` in the knit file. This is literally bad, it's not how programs are supposed to either be configured or exit on error. And it's a document converter written in Haskell ... all that nice compiler type checking & enforcing was totally in vain! WELP! Ok, so ... [How to increase heap memory in pandoc execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599860/how-to-increase-stack-space-overflow-for-pandoc-in-r) did not work. Finally I gave the VM 10 GiB of RAM. Mitigated the problems as I don't have to reboot in between "works once only" knit processes.

Answer (score -1):

Using the current version of RStudio into ubuntu 14.04 any of this two commands makes the ubuntu load more and more memory until crash:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US")
```