# Troubleshooting Memory Allocation Issues in Deployed Plumber API with Large Datasets"

Tags: r, plumber

I have previously inquired about this issue without obtaining a solution. To provide more details in the hope of resolving the problem:

I have developed a Plumber API that is deployed on a private server. This API receives data, which is then utilized to generate a report using an R Markdown (RMD) file. The sequence of events involves the API receiving data, invoking the RMD file, the RMD file utilizing the data, and ultimately generating the report.

When running this Plumber API locally, I encounter no issues, regardless of whether the dataset is large or small. However, the API deployed on the server seems to struggle when handling substantial datasets. The specific error message is as follows:

```
output file: rapport_.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS rapport_.knit.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /app/rapport_.docx --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --highlight-style tango --reference-doc tmplt.docx
Killed
<simpleError: pandoc document conversion failed with error 137>
```

This issue does not manifest locally; I run the same code with the same data, and the report is successfully generated.

Upon further investigation, I came across a few posts suggesting a solution involving the use of `pandoc_args`, such as in the discussions found here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/315  and here  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-August/431647.html and here as well [How to increase stack space overflow for pandoc in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599860/how-to-increase-stack-space-overflow-for-pandoc-in-r) .

In response, I updated my RMD file to include the following YAML front matter:

```
---
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), 'Version du %d %B %Y', locale = 'fr_FR')`"
title: "Rapport"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    toc: TRUE
    pandoc_args: [
      "+RTS", "-K1G",
      "-RTS"
    ]
---
```

Despite these changes, when calling my RMD file using `rmarkdown::render("rapport_.Rmd")`, the memory allocation remains at `+RTS -K512m -RTS`, although it is intended to be `"-K1G"` now.

Any insights on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What resources do you have the the server? I'll assume that it's modestly-resourced, meaning your local may be "just enough" to get the task done. I think you have two options: (1) if you're using Posit Connect remotely, confirm that your _Settings » Runtime » RAM Settings_ is unset or can be increased; (2) see if you can increase RAM on the remote server itself; and (3) refactor your app to see if the internal code can be made more frugal.

Comment: The server has 2GO of RAM ! I even went and increased it to 8GO ! the problem still persisted

Comment: 2Go of RAM is not much, 8Go seems reasonable, though. To where are you deploying it? What packages are being used? Lacking anything else, I think I stick with #3 above.

Comment: The API does a lot of work so I'm using over 30 different packages. I have two questions please: 1) why would a docker image of the same API work locally but not when on a private server? could be something else other the RAM? 2) I'm pretty sure my code isn't optimsed memory wise. What could help to make my code use less memory?

Comment: (1) Different R versions, R package versions, OS-level libraries, data. Different setup of LaTeX (and `knitr`, `pandoc`). Possibly resource limitations imposed such as max-ram per container (regardless of ram on the system). Custom user settings (`options(.)`) set differently. (2) That's a huge (and loaded) question. Remove rmarkdown from the equation, try to do just the inner calculations inside the docker container. If you find problems then you might consider [profiling](https://posit.co/blog/profiling-with-rstudio-and-profvis/), otherwise ... not sure yet.